# numpy - use array like a dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I need a solution to use an array like a dict. i can not use a dict, because I use numba and there I only can commit an array

```
corr_header = np.arange(0, 10).tolist()
corr_header_nr =  np.arange(10, 20).tolist()

corr_arr = list(zip(corr_header_nr, corr_header))
corr_arr
```

I obtain to search after a value in corr_header_nr and get the value from corr_header. For example search for 13 and get 3 as output. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and return if there is a match.

```
def getoutput(key):
    return [k[1] for k in corr_arr if k[0]==key]

print(getoutput(13))
```